# Weak convergence in Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

In Rudin's book <> Page 66, it says "If $X$ is a infinite dimensional topology vector space, then $X$ under the weak topology is not locally bounded" .
Hence I think the topology of any (infinite)Banach space $X$ is different from the weak topology, for $X$ is locally bounded.
Since the topology determines the convergence, can I get that weak convergence is equivalent    to original convergence in any (infinite)Banach spaces?
Thank you.

Comment: For nets, in infinite-dimensional normed spaces, weak convergence is never equivalent to norm-convergence. Norm-convergence always implies weak convergence, and there are some spaces ($\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ for example) in which every weakly convergent _sequence_ is also norm-convergent, but that is a rare exception.

Comment: Thank you. I'll appreciate it very much if you could add more details.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good counter-example to keep in mind, only using basic Hilbert analysis.

Let $E$ be an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, with $(e_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a Hilbert basis.  Consider $x \in E$ : then, 
$$||x||^{2} = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |\langle x, e_{n} \rangle |^{2}$$
and therefore, the real sequence $(\langle x, e_{n} \rangle )$ converges to $0$ (keep in mind that $E' = E$ since $E$ is a Hilbert space), which proves the fact that the sequence $(e_{n})$ is weakly convergent to $0$. However, since $||e_{n}|| = 1$ for every $n$, this sequence does not (strongly) converge to $0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I want to ask "weak convergence is never equivalent to original convergence in any (infinite)Banach spaces?". My mistake.